# how to change directory from inside unix shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
change(){
read -p "Enter username" q
sudo su $q
cd /home/$q
pwd

}
change
```

without using sudo I am able to change directory, but when I do sudo su, cd does not work ? What could be possible reason behind this and solution for this

Comment: I think `sudo` is throwing some error and the script is getting terminated after that. So its not executing commands after that. Debug the script to check if the `cd` command is getting executed or not.

Comment: yes because of sudo it is happening that i understood but what could be workaround or solution if i want to put sudo and cd in a single script

Comment: I think you need `sudo -i` take a look here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/su-vs-sudo-s-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bash. No need to cd into home folder of the user - it is already there with `sudo -i`

Answer (score 0):

When you run `sudo su $q`, you are logging in as $q.  Then, the script waits until the `sudo su` command exits, before continuing to execute.  The rest of the script will execute after you type `exit`-- including the change of directories.

If you wish for the `su` to end up in a different directory, you would *first* change the directory, and *then* run the `sudo su` command.

Comment: is there any way so that I could do sudo first and then cd, because if i will not do sudo then while changing directory i will get error msg permission denied, sudo is must to do . could you suggest some workaround  ?

Comment: Well, you should be able to do first "sudo cd yourDirectory", and then "sudo su".  Let me know if that works.